# Equivalent Definitions of the $L_2$ inner product.

Tags: analysis, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces

If $g \in L_2(\mathbb{R})$, then we can define the $L_2$ norm to have the following relationship: $\|g\|_2^2 = \int_\mathbb{R} g^2$. If $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, then we can define the norm of $L_2(A)$ to be $\|g\|_A = \left(\int_A g^2\right)^{1/2}$, or equivalently, one can define $\|g\|_A = \inf\{\|h\|_2: h\in L_2(\mathbb R), h_{|A} = g\}$.

My $\textbf{question}$ deals with when $L_2(A)$ is a Hilbert space with inner product $\langle g,h\rangle_A = \int_A g\bar{h}$. Is there an equivalent definition like they use for the norm? That is to say something like,

$
\begin{align*}
\langle g,h \rangle_A = \inf \left\{\int_{\mathbb{R}} g^{'}h^{'} : g^{'},h^{'}\in L_2(\mathbb R), g^{'}_{|A} = g, h^{'}_{|A} = h\right\}
\end{align*}
$

I am a bit uncertain because of the inner product is not non-negative and so I am not sure if this definition holds.

Comment: A complex inner product space (i.e. a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ with an inner product) has a norm so that $\| x \|^2 = \langle x,x \rangle$. So in the case of $L^2(X)$ with complex-valued functions you get $\int_X |g|^2$, which is nonnegative.

Comment: That I already understand, but I am not looking for definitions of the norm, rather a definition for the inner product over a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ characterised by functions on $L_2(\mathbb{R})$, see the first paragraph of the question as an example for an equivalent definition for the norm.

Comment: Perhaps the polarization identity would help.

Comment: Yes I have been trying to use that under your suggestion, but it is proving difficult to use at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $H$ to be a Hilbert space, $X$ normed linear space. Assume that there is an injection
$$
I\in \mathcal L(X,H).
$$
Then one can define an inner product on $X$
$$
\langle x,y\rangle_X := \langle Ix,Iy\rangle_H.
$$
The space $X$ equipped with the norm $\|x\|_I:=\sqrt{\langle x,y\rangle_X}$ is pre-Hilbert space.

In the case of $H=L^2(\mathbb R)$, $X=L^2(A)$, define $I$ by
$$
x\in L^2(A) \mapsto (Ix)(t):=\chi_A(t)x(t),
$$
so $I$ extends $x$ outside of $A$ by $0$. In this case, the usual inner product on $L^2(A)$ coincides with the inner product induced by the injection.

The construction of the inner product on $L^2(A)$ with infimum as in the question does not work: the infimum is always $-\infty$.